# Identifying Triangle with if/else

Tags: ruby

Question is a user gives 3 sides and identifies triangles, like equilateral, isosceles and scalene. Here is my coding, I don't know why gives any sides that always show up "invalid". I think it's logic wrong, but I can't figure out.

```
puts "please input the length of 3 sides:"
a = gets.chomp.to_i
b = gets.chomp.to_i 
c = gets.chomp.to_i

if a + b <= c
  puts "invalid"
elsif a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0
  puts "invalid"
else    
  if a == b && b == c
    puts"equilateral triangle"
  elsif a == b
    puts"isosceles triangle"  
  else    
    puts"scalene triangle"
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not able to reproduce your problem: when I run it with 50/50/50, I get the expected output of "equilateral triangle".

Comment: It looks like your validity test improves if the sides are sorted (small to large) `a,b,c = [gets.to_i, gets.to_i, gets.to_i].sort` .  A way to count the number of equal sides would be  counting the unique sides. `[a,b,c].uniq.size` .

Comment: Further to @steenslag's observation, try `puts "#{ ["equilateral", "isosceles", "scalene"][3.times.map { gets }.uniq.size-1] } triangle"`. If `3`, `4`, and `3` is entered,  `3.times.map { gets } #=> ["3\n", "4\n", "3\n"]`, `3.times.map { gets }.uniq #=> ["3\n", "4\n"]` and `3.times.map { gets }.uniq.size - 1 #=> 1`, so  `["equilateral", "isosceles", "scalene"][1] #=> "isosceles"`. There's no need for `chomp` or `to_i`. In real life, however, you'd want to ensure that entries were valid (no `"4"`, `"-2"` or `"cat"`).

Comment: When the input is `a = 1000, b = 1, c = 1`, the result is `"scalene triangle"`, but it should return `"invalid"`. In my post a fix I suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your code always prints "invalid" makes me think that input is passed in on one line instead of being on separate lines. For example, when the input is:

```
50 50 50
```

instead of getting 50 in all three variables you would get 50 in a and 0 in b, c. This is because `gets` takes in an entire line instead of taking one value.

In such an event, this is what you need:

```
a, b, c = gets.split.map{ |value| value.to_i }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better more effective way to do this is to store the values of the triangle sides into a hash first, the value of of each triangle side will be the keys, and the value of each key can be the repeats. This will work with strings too.

**Here is an Example.**

```
# First you get an array, you can use gets.chomp as string and split to array, whichever way you choose, but in the end we end up with an array, and we pass the array to the method.

def triangle_type(arr) 
  # Create new empty hash
  repeated_sides = Hash.new(0) 

  # First make sure the array is only a length of three. (this is optional)
  if arr.length == 3
    # Iterate through each value in the array and store it to to a hash to find duplicates
    arr.each do |x|
      repeated_sides[x] += 1
    end

    # sort the hash by it's values in descending order, for logic to work later.
    repeated_sides = repeated_sides.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h
    
    # uncomment this below to see the duplicate sides hash
    #puts "#{repeated_sides}"
  
    # Iterate through the sorted hash, apply logic starting from highest and first value the iterator will find.
    repeated_sides.each do |k,v|
      return v == 3 ? 'Equilateral Triangle' : v == 2 ? 'Isosceles Triangle' : 'Scalene Triangle'
    end

  end

  # Return Not a triangle if the condition fails
  return 'Not a triangle'
end

# Test with integers
puts triangle_type([4,1,2,5]) # output: Not a triangle
puts triangle_type([3,3,3]) # output: Equilateral Triangle
puts triangle_type([4,3,3]) # output: Isosceles Triangle
puts triangle_type([4,2,3]) # output: Scalene Triangle

# Test with strings
puts triangle_type(['4','1','2','5']) # output: Not a triangle
puts triangle_type(['3','3','3']) # output: Equilateral Triangle
puts triangle_type(['4','3','3']) # output: Isosceles Triangle
puts triangle_type(['4','2','3']) # output: Scalene Triangle

puts triangle_type(['a','a','a']) # output: Equilateral Triangle
puts triangle_type(['a','c','c']) # output: Isosceles Triangle
puts triangle_type(['a','b','c']) # output: Scalene Triangle
```

Answer (score -1):

Skipping user inputs, since I can not reproduce the error (even if Unihedron found a fix) there is still a problem with the logic.

When the input is `a = 1000, b = 1, c = 1`, the result is `"scalene triangle"`, but it should return `"invalid"`. Below a fix I suggest.

Let's store the input in an array (already converted into integer or float):

```
sides = [a, b, c]
```

First you need to check that all sides are positive:

```
sides.all? { |x| x > 0 }
```

Then, check that the sum of two sides is greater than the other:

```
sides.combination(2).map{ |x| x.sum }.zip(sides.reverse).all? { |xy, z| xy > z }
```

Finally (I'm missing something?), to pick the triangle denomination you can use an hash accessing it by sides.uniq result:

```
triangle_kinds = {1 => 'equilateral', 2 => 'isosceles', 3 => 'scalene'}
triangle_kinds[sides.uniq.size]
```

---

Used the following methods over array (enumerable):

- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-zip
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-reverse
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sum
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq